# Loop Counter running very slow

Tags: sql, loops

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1
WHILE(@LoopCounter < 1000)

BEGIN

SELECT account, SUM(amt_paid) FROM transactions
WHERE account = '49944928'
    GROUP BY account
        HAVING SUM(amt_paid) <> 0.00
            COMPUTE SUM (SUM(amt_paid))
SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

END
```

I am trying to get this to return results every 5 seconds, but it runs for about 5 minutes and then returns the results about 100 times then goes back to loading up the next 4 or 5 minutes of results.

Anyway I can make this run a little quicker so it actually shows the results every 5 seconds?

Comment: `COMPUTE` is deprecated in SQL Server.  You should instead be using `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS` or something similar.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for such thing http://sqlhints.com/2013/11/05/printselect-statement-messages-within-while-loop-or-batch-of-statement-is-not-displayed-immediately-after-its-execution-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
DECLARE @iteration AS INT
SET @iteration = 1
WHILE(@iteration<=10)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Start of Iteration ' + CAST(@iteration AS VARCHAR)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    PRINT 'End Of Iteration ' + CAST(@iteration AS VARCHAR)
    SET @iteration+=1   

    RAISERROR('',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!